# jScrollPane theme with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I want to apologize now for my bad english, i hope you will understand what i want:

I recently used the plugin jquery 'jScrollPane' on my website malossane.fr/sqf/. Everything is ok, but i appeared to not be able to make the only little change i wanted.
In fact , it is very simple in the idea, but my css scripting level is very bad.

Just now, i have something like that :http://malossane.fr/usb-file-723

And i want something like that :[What i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHyct.png)

In fact, i want the .jspDrag to be larger than the .jspVerticalBar that should have a width of 5px. But if i put a width of 5px for the vertical bar, the .jspDrag width become also  of 5px although i want him to stay at 16px.

Is someone able to help me?
Thanx a lot,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of possible solutions:

1. You could use a background image on the `.jspTrack` which is the width you require and centered e.g.

   ```
   .jspTrack
   {
       background: #fff url(/path/to/image.png) repeat-y 5px 0;
   }
   ```

   This way even through the `.jspTrack` is the width of the `.jspDrag` it's background makes it look less wide.
2. You could try using negative margins on the `.jspDrag` to pull it outside the `.jspTrack` e.g.

   ```
   .jspVerticalBar .jspTrack
   {
       width: 5px;
       background: #c4c4c4;
   }
   .jspVerticalBar .jspDrag
   {
       margin: 0 -5px;
       width: 15px;
       background: #363636
   }
   ```

   Possibly you could use `left` instead of the negative margin.

Both of these solutions are untested but they should give you a good start...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about that plugin but i can give u a solution
set the color of .jspVerticalBar to transparent or same color as that of background 
and put another vertical bar (fake one . . ) right on the .jspVerticalbar so that it looks as what you want